# Magento 2.2 unable to create new account

Tags: magento2.2, customer-account

Whenever I try to create new customer account from home page, the page refreshes after submit and nothing is submitted. There is no any error message.

I have check the `register.phtml` file in `module-customer` and it has form key as follow.

```
<?php /* @noEscape */ echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

However, my `app/design/frontend/Magento` folder is empty and does not contain any files.

Comment: In which browser you are facing issue ?

Comment: Please use ip rather than localhost

Comment: @Yogesh  i have configure /etc/hosts so that www.test.com will point to localhost  but it still redirect back to localhost for magento. Do note that i have wordpress file hosted in localhost as well but it do not redirect back to localhost. Where else do i need to change

Comment: you need to setup virtual host for that, you can change your url http://youripaddress/magento-ce-2-2/

Comment: You are not able to login with localhost in chrome browser

Comment: @vincentsty, I have been facing the same issue after u[pgrade from magento2.2.3 to magento2.3.1  could you please advise how did you fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use your `ip/yourmagentofolder` instead of `localhost` and change same in "`core_config_data`" table in secure/unsecure url .

If you are using virtual host than point your virtual host to your `IP` instead of `localhost` .

And don't forget to clear cache .

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to your database localhost/ then you look for the **core_config_data** table change all the localhost to your IP.

Then go to your Magento project <**project folder>/app/etc** in this folder you have the **env.php** file, change the localhost to your IP.

Then clear your cache